# Understanding the Generalized Conjugate Residual (GCR) method.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following description of the GCR algorithm:

[image]

I think I understand all the steps until:
$$\beta = (v^i, r^{i -1})\\u^i:= u^{i-1} + \beta s^i$$

**Question:** What does $\beta s^i$ look like? Should I compute $\beta s^i = v^i s_1^i + r^{i-1}s_2^i$?

I'm confused as I don't really understand how you can define a vector by two row vectors; should it mean that $\beta$ is a matrix?

Comment: $\beta$ is a scalar product between two vectors : a scalar. $s^i$ is a vector so $\beta s^i$ will be the $s^i$ vector scaled by $\beta$

Comment: I think you interpret $(v^i,r^{i-1})$ as concatenation but it means $v^i \cdot r^{i-1}$ (scalar product)

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks a  lot!!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out correctly in the comments, $(v^i, r^{i-1})$ means $v^i\cdot r^{r-1}$. I checked the algorithm in python and using this interpretation everything works as expected.